# Adding JSON Strings transparently to a map/list

Tags: java, json, string, serialization

I am getting from an external source (Database) JSON strings that I need to collect together into a result that is Map (key is the record key and the value is actually a  string that includes a Json formatted data). So for example I will get 3 records from DB as follows:

```
 "record1", "{ "type":"recType1", "data": "somedata" }"
 "record2", "{ "type":"recType1", "data": "someotherdata" }"
 "recrod3", "{ "type":"recType1", "data": "yetanotherdata" }"
```

I don't want to parse the data of the jsons in the replies (No need).
If I add those as "String" then I will get the " escaped (\") which is a problem of course.
  For example, the record1 value from above will look like this:

```
"{ \"type\":\"recType1\", \"data\": \"somedata\" }"
```

How do I create a resulting Json that combines them all? Is there a way to add something "transparently" without it being processed by an internal serializer that escapes the content of the value?

Comment: Your first extract is not valid JSON. What is the real JSON?

Comment: when you typed gson did you perhaps mean json?

Comment: Do you have any code that represents an attempt?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is the eval() function, here an example using your json object:

```
eval("result= { \"type\":\"recType1\", \"data\": \"somedata\" }")
document.write(result["type"]);
```

This will parse your object as javascript code, and you can retrieve your values.
Cheers.

Comment: What is the desired outcome ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Java Class for the object you are getting from JSON,
USE GSON 2.0 API to parse it to java object ArrayList.

Extract it and create the MAP.

Note : GSON 2.0 have taken care of all data type to be parsed properly according to your class.

Comment: Parsing the JSON I get from database is not desired, mainly for performance. The desired outcome of encoding the sample entries would be (2 items not 3) [ { "type": "recType1", "data" : "somedata" }, { "type" : "recordType1", "data" : "someotherdata" } ] BUT when I am doing that through the Set<String> I will get instead a JSON that looks like this: [ "{\"type\:\"recordType1\", \"data\":\"somedata\" }", "{\"type\":\"recordType1\", \"data\":\"someotherdata\"}"] instead. So the client of the result will need to first unpack each element as a string before unpack of data

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code that shows the problem:

```
public Set<String> doQuery(String query)
    {
        Set<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        boolean haveMore = true;

        while(haveMore)
        {
            String entry = DB.read(query);
            if (entry != null)
                result.add(entry);
            else
                haveMore = false;
        }
        return result;
    }


    public Map<String, Object> generateReport(String query)
    {
        Map<String, Object> report = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Set<String> result = doQuery(query);
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.size() != 0)
            {
                report.put("result", "success");
                report.put("query", query);
                report.put("count", result.size());
                report.put("objects", result);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        return report;
    }

    public String getReportAsJson(String query)
    {
        Map<String, Object> report = generateReport(query);
        if (report != null)
        {
            Gson g = new Gson();
            return g.toJson(report);
        }
        return "{ \"result\": \"fail\" }";
    }
```

If you take the result each Json document retrieved from DB is serialized as String from the Map, and the result is all " in the Json are escaped.